# PostgreSQL row not appearing while the row is being updated but appears again afterwards

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, with columns **created_at** for when the record was first created/inserted and **updated_at** that get updated every time a record is altered.

When I take a snapshot of the table which is actively being updated, one record i.e **ID 8** is not in the snapshot but after the updating has stopped and I query the table again, the record is now visible again.

Any logical reason why this is the case?

**SnapShot of User Table**

```
select * from users where created_at <= '2022-01-16' or updated_at <= '2022-01-16';
 id |             email              |    password     |  status  |  role  |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+--------------------------------+-----------------+----------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  9 | greg_newman97@gmail.com        | sUMuOM_gXCPxz19 | disabled | seller | 2022-01-01 15:39:45.447-03 | 2022-01-01 12:54:01.023-03
 10 | cynthia_grey@gmail.com         | iOkZQhc7JSsQcpY | disabled | seller | 2020-02-13 13:39:16.26-03  | 2019-12-18 17:02:37.938-03
 11 | nancy_white@yahoo.com          | Bw2OhPUtIRcWxZF | active   | seller | 2018-07-30 08:01:29.942-03 | 2019-09-03 10:50:40.314-03
(3 rows)
```

**User table** *queried later after table updates have stopped*

```
select * from users where created_at <= '2022-01-16' or updated_at <= '2022-01-16';
 id |             email              |    password     |  status  |  role  |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+--------------------------------+-----------------+----------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  8 | peter_nash@gmail.com           | qYHsmrKWaiaiZxI | disabled | seller | 2019-09-06 21:43:08.043-03 | 2022-01-16 16:04:25.233-03
  9 | greg_newman97@gmail.com        | sUMuOM_gXCPxz19 | disabled | seller | 2022-01-01 15:39:45.447-03 | 2022-01-01 12:54:01.023-03
 10 | cynthia_grey@gmail.com         | iOkZQhc7JSsQcpY | disabled | seller | 2020-02-13 13:39:16.26-03  | 2019-12-18 17:02:37.938-03
 11 | nancy_white@yahoo.com          | Bw2OhPUtIRcWxZF | active   | seller | 2018-07-30 08:01:29.942-03 | 2019-09-03 10:50:40.314-03
(4 rows)
```

**NB** I'm querying from a replica database

Comment: We would need full details on how the replication is being achieved.

Comment: No, this is unexpected. You should describe the update procedure in detail, ideally in the form of an SQL script that can be used to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: this is possible only in one case parallel insert into the table and replication.Since the old data will be visible when updating / deleting

Comment: @arutar could you expound on your statement?

Comment: if you are currently updating this row, it might be locked.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible only in one case parallel insert into the table and replication.

Since the old data will be visible when updating / deleting

Let's imagine that we have two parallel queries to the database.

And the table `test_table`

```
create table test_table (id serial, t text);

insert into test_table (t) values ('11111'),('22222'),('33333');
```

case one **deletion** and **modification**

**query 1**

```
select * from test_table;

id |   t
----+-------
  1 | 11111
  2 | 22222
  3 | 33333
```

**query 2**

here we assume that replication is a long operation and a parallel update is possible

```
begin;

update test_table set t='00000' where id=1;

commit;
```

until **query 2** is **committed**, the data returned by the first **query** will be old

```
id |   t
----+-------
  1 | 11111
  2 | 22222
  3 | 33333
```

and only after committing **query 2**

**query 1** will return

```
id |   t
----+-------
  2 | 22222
  3 | 33333
  1 | 00000
```

**Accordingly, replication will reflect an instant data snapshot. All changes that occurred after the start of replication will not be visible until the start of a new replication**

and the example above shows that if the data was already in the database, then it will be reflected in the query, and if the insertion occurred after the start of replication, then the data will not be visible

**case two data insert**

**query 1**

until query 2 is committed

```
select * from test_table;

id |   t
----+-------
  2 | 22222
  3 | 33333
  1 | 00000
```

**query 2**

```
begin;

insert into test_table (t) values ('11111');

commit;
```

and only after committing **query 2**

**query 1** will return

```
id |   t
----+-------
  2 | 22222
  3 | 33333
  1 | 00000
  4 | 11111
```